# I don't understand a c# line of code and can't find the answer online

Tags: c#

I'm starting to learn C# and .NET in my university and I'm having a hard time figuring out how some example code works.

My problem is with the following syntax. The class `componente` is a subclass of Form1.

```
public class componente
{
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public componente siguiente;
}
```

What I don't understand is the line `public componente siguiente`. I have searched in Google and Stack Overflow but I don't know the name of that and can't find an answer.

I don't understand if it is a variable, a method or something else.

Comment: [Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields). I recommend following some basic programming tutorials as they should clear these things up for you.

Comment: That's a public field. A field is a class level variable (as apposed to local variables that are declared inside methods).

Comment: Just watch beginner day 1 tutorial videos on YouTube..

Comment: I did, and spend almost half an hour lloking for something I don't know the name. I also reviewed a basic C# tutorial and find nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic syntax for declaring a variable is

```
[public|private|protected] Type Name;
```

The basic syntax for declaring a method is

```
[public|private|protected] Return-Type Name(Arguments) { Body }
```

(careful: this is just very basic syntax)

Hence you are most likely approaching a variable declaration here. The type is componente, which means siguiente contains another Object of that Class. This looks like you are programming a List.

You could search for Tutorials on how to programm a List in C# and you are going to see more code that looks like yours.

However, basically you have a value (a number in your case) and a "pointer" to the next Object holding the next number.

In other words: Your class is holding a reference to Objects of the very same class. Now I know you are trying to achieve a stack, which is not really different. What you will end up with is something like this:

[number|siguiente---------->[number|siguiente--------->[number|siguiente]]]

where siguiente is the next Object of the same class and everything inside the brackets [] is a componente. Notice how I only can close all of the brackets at the end, because the first Object will contain a siguiente (next) Object of the same Type. So the root component will contain all other components.

In a stack you can just take the last component added (last in first out)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am programming a Stack. Almost all examples of stacks I found used arrays; but that line of code confuses me.

Comment: @Computer My answer is still valid. Stacks and Lists are also not really different in this matter. It would be better if your university would do this in C though.

Comment: @Computer Edited my answer, maybe this is more visual.

Answer (score 2):

Notice **componente** is also your class name, this means componente class has a field **siguiente**, which is a type of itself (componente). It is a recursive relationship.

E.g., a Person class may have a field **father**, which is also a type of Person.

Comment: Who vote it down, I am explaining the exact reason why @Computer is confused.

Comment: Public fields do not conform to the OOP encapsulation. Also, something that looks like `public componente() {}` without the name of the field is actually a default constructor!

Comment: @engineforce Thanks for answering, the program is for implementing a Stack and they want me to do It this way. There are a  lot of metods in the program that use "siguiente" (spanish for next); top; etc.
What you are saying is "next is a variable of the type component, and is an atribute of the class component"?

Comment: @Computer, you are exactly right. Component can have other Components. Like a [Linked List](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/linked_list_algorithms.htm).

Answer (score 0):

That `public` word is a reserved word of C# language, it is an access modifier of that property/class. I.e., you define who has access to that Class/Property (only the class where they were defined, outside classes, etc.).

`Class` is that you defined a class.

`componente` is the name of that class.

---

in `public componente siguiente;`

here you are defining a field (simply a variable).

`public` is the access modified.

`componente` is the type of that field (i.e., you are defining a variable of type class `componente`).

`siguiente` is the name of that field (or variable).

I would watch some videos or read the basics of C# language (normally about 200 book pages) before asking (even if you find some ambiguous things at the beginning).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but my problem is with the line "public componente siguiente;" in english: "public component next". Those are stuf for implementing with methods a Stack.